# Postgres - Table design to store user wise folder structure

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-modeling, hierarchical-data

Im going to create a design for an application that looks like a Google drive, anyone can create files on the root directory or creating inside folders (and subfolders)

Now on the user's console, I have to show all the top level folders, a down arrow will be there, it the folder contains any subfolder, then if we click the down arrow, all the subfolders inside the folder will be visible.

Sample:

[image]

[image]

Im not sure, what kind of Table design I should choose for this, can someone help me with this?

Comment: A simple self-referencing table would be enough: `id`, `dirname`, `parentid`. The root will then have a `parentid` of 0.

Comment: @derstauner: the root folder should have `parentid` with `NULL`  otherwise you can't have proper foreign keys in the table

Comment: Do I need to create this table with the user id?

Comment: That would depend on how you plan on using each user. Are the sub folders user specific. If so then first thought would be create a second level under Main Folder for each user.

Comment: The screenshot is for one specific user, the other use may have a different folder and subfolder

Answer (score 3):

You can create a self referencing hierarchical table for that. There will be `parent_id` column to store the id of parent folder. For top level folder `parent_id` will be null.

Below can be the list of columns for your table.

```
1. id -- integer auto increment primary key.
2. Name -- Name of the folder
3. Parent_id -- id of parent folder. Referencing id column of this table. Null for top level folders.
4. Sequence_Number -- In which sequence folders will be displayed. Folder with same parent_id will be displayed order by seqeunce_number. You can change it from front end so  that user can choose to rearrange folder sequence.
5. description -- description of a folder. If you want to put it.
6. user_id -- Foreign key to user table.
```